# Why am I getting NoReverseMatch error with no arguments found?

Tags: django, django-views, backend, django-urls

Error:

> NoReverseMatch at /leachers/11/donate/ 
> Reverse for 'donate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['leachers/(?P[0-9]+)/donate/$']

[image: Error here]

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def donate(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UserDonateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.donator = request.user
            user.save()
            return redirect('leacher_list')
    else:
        form = forms.UserDonateForm()
    return render(request,'my_app/donation_form.html',{'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import donate

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.HomePageView.as_view(),name='home_page'),
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('leachers/',views.LeacherListView.as_view(),name='leacher_list'),
    path('leachers/<int:pk>/donate/',donate,name='donate'),
]
```

here I am assigning pk to link:

```
{% for member in leacher_list %}
        <h4>Name : {{ member.name }}</h4>
        <h5>Address : {{ member.address }}</h5>
        <h5>Location : {{ member.location }}</h5>
        <!--original href="donate" -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'donate' pk=member.pk %}" role="button">Donate</a>
```

I am new to django.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `app_name` before namespace in url. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'my_app:donate' pk=member.pk %}" role="button">Donate</a>
```

Here we consider `my_app` is `app_name`. Please try this.

Comment: tried...didn't work...Anyways I have only one app in my  project.

Comment: Got it now...I was giving url in action tag for form...After removing action tag I did get it right...also #path('leachers//donate/<int:pk>',donate,name='donate') I messed up with this...I corrected it afterwards .